# Laravel 4(.1), Eloquent and Relationships

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a post model, a user model and a comment model.

My users can post posts and also can comment to posts.

I want to get the comments of posts with posts but, my users can also block users too.

I mean, if the active user has some other blocked users, and if the comments of post has comments created by these users, I have to exclude them.

And here comes the problem.

```php
$posts = $user()->posts()->get();

$blockedUserIdentifiers = (array) $viewer->getBlockedUserIdentifiers();

$posts->with(array('comments' => function($query) use ($blockedUserIdentifiers)
{
    if( ! empty($blockedUserIdentifiers))
        $query->whereNotIn('user_id', $blockedUserIdentifiers);
}))->with('user'); // ? Ups?
```

I want to use relationships of posts and also comments, because the work is not finished here. But if I use foreach on posts array, it will be very strange to continue and; if I use foreach on posts object, I is hard for me to continue.

Because i have blockedUser condition, I can not eager load too.

What is the best practice of my case or, how should I add `$comments` result object to `$posts` object like laravel does?

Or how can I continue to add relationship results to that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting constraints on multiple relationships with `with()`.

```
$posts->with(array('comments' => function($query) use ($blockedUserIdentifiers)
{
    // if( ! empty($blockedUserIdentifiers))
    //     $query->whereNotIn('user_id', $blockedUserIdentifiers);
}, 'comments.user', function($query) use ($blockedUserIdentifiers)
{
    // Constraints on the users can go here
    if( ! empty($blockedUserIdentifiers))
        $query->whereNotIn('id', $blockedUserIdentifiers);
}))->get();
```

Or doing it while echoing.

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    // If you want to keep your relationships clean, you can just not echo the post instead
    if(array_search($post->user_id, $blockedUserIdentifiers) !== false) {
        continue;
    }

    echo $post->content;
    foreach($post->comments as $comment) {
        echo $comment->user;
        echo $comment->content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I prefer to use database queries where possible. You know, performance matters.

Comment: I agree, it's better to have it done in SQL.  I modified my answer more to show that there are actually two solutions here.  Have you tried the first, which is adding another relationship with your `with()` statment?

Comment: I am afraid writing that way will result comments with no-users?

Comment: Then instead of `with(..)`, use `whereHas(...)`.  It will only return comments that have users.